# How can we store configuration data in new asp.net vnext?

Tags: asp.net-core

How can we store configuration data in new asp.net vnext? web.config still there(system.web removed, so no any web.config,but I like it) or using new json file for configuration data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure exactly what kind of data you are trying to store but this work for me. I created this file myconfig.json and store that data that I need in a JSON format.

This will register your configuration file, I added this code in the startup.cs page.

```
Configuration = new Configuration()
.AddJsonFile("config.json")
.AddJsonFile("myconfig.json")
.AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

To get the data that you need from the your JSON file you need to this at any point on your code.

```
IConfiguration Configuration = new Configuration().AddJsonFile("myconfig.json");
var jsonNodes = Configuration.Get("SomeJsonNode");
string someJsonString = Configuration.Get("someJsonString");
```

FYI: At the moment that I tested that code json array were not supported. Not sure if they fixed that now.

Comment: Thanks , I got it .we can save our setting in json file and we can retrieve anywhere in code, like we did on web.config.

Comment: no problem, I was reading some blog and they mention that if you need app variables is good to have like that but if you going to store connection strings and other secrets variables is better to use  Environment Variables if you using azure the portal has a nice interface to add these. Please if you can mark the question as answer

Comment: Note that there is no need to add "myconfig.json", "config.json" is for your use.

Comment: The only since with that if you modify your config.json that will trigger a in memory compilation or semantic compilation if you have a second file for just your application variables you have more separation. Even Microsoft remcomeded that way, when you create a sample web site there is a file call configuration.json that stores the connections strings for the DB

Answer (score 6):

Configuration used best is a starting point to strongly typed options. So what you want to do in startup is register an Options object, set it up with data you read from configuration, and get it from the DI system in the rest of your code.

Example:

Create an Options object

```
public class ApplicationOptions
{
    public bool MyOption { get; set; }
}
```

Read the configuration and setup the options object then register it in DI

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{         
    // rest of setup

    var applicationOptions = new ApplicationOptions();
    string myOption;
    if (configuration.TryGet("MyOption", out myOption) &&
            myOption.Equals("True", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        applicationOptions.MyOption = true;
    }

    // For the scenario above also the code below will work.
    // It is currently limited to desktop (ASPNET50, NET45) only.
    // services.Configure<ApplicationOptions>(configuration);

    services.AddInstance<ApplicationOptions>(applicationOptions);

    // more setup
}
```

And resolve it in your code

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index(ApplicationOptions options)
    {
        // do something with the options
    }
}
```

Edit: with any practical reusable options object, the code setting it up will probably happen outside the startup class.

Comment: Options != configuration. Also, in this example, what is `diSystem`, and why would you read from config manually? Doesn't Options automatically read from config? What value is Options adding here? In fact, is this example even using Options?

Comment: 1. Options is the strongly typed way to pass around configuration data. The value is that you can get at options from DI at any other point in your app in a strongly typed way without having to recreate the Configuration object. So yes they are not the same, but for practical purposes that is the way to go. 2. Options do not read directly from configuration, you have to hand write the code (either as in this example or in some other method)

Comment: Doesn't Options automatically read from config? Or have a built-in way to do that? E.g. in https://github.com/aspnet/Options/blob/4c55cc9286dfd0b09d2b81a801e614e634b8b474/src/Microsoft.Framework.OptionsModel/OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.cs and https://github.com/aspnet/Options/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.OptionsModel/OptionsServices.cs there's a ton of code that reads from config and uses reflection to set the Options properties.

Comment: There is a way to use configuration, it has the following limitations: 1. It is an opt-in. 2. It is currently not available for Cloud Optimized CLR 3. It supports simple conversions (like string -> int).

Comment: You should still probably show the 'nice' way as well, services.Configure<ApplicationOptions>(configuration)

Comment: See my comments above, it is limited to simple types and only works on desktop .net.

Comment: What if the only place you want to access this config information is from a referenced project/class library? (ie data access layer needs access to the connection string in the web project)

Answer (score 6):

In the breaking changes (beta 6), Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel assembly name changed to [Microsoft.Framework.Configuration](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/25) 
This is the modified startup class

```
 public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{
     var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath).
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
     Configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
}
```