# How is configuration data protected in ASP .NET 5?

Tags: asp.net-core

Rather than requiring `Web.config`, ASP .NET 5 provides a number of options to provide configuration data. Info on this can be found at:

- [Introducing ASP .NET 5](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-asp-net-5) by Scott Guthrie
- [How can we store configuration data in new asp.net vnext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232364/how-can-we-store-configuration-data-in-new-asp-net-vnext) (StackOverflow)
- [ASP.NET vNext Moving Parts: IConfiguration](http://whereslou.com/2014/05/23/asp-net-vnext-moving-parts-iconfiguration/) by Louis DeJardin

There's an interesting question in the comments section of ScottGu's article:

> The config.json file in the example, how is that protected by the webserver/http server? web.config is protected by IIS, but if any file can be used (which is great), it also comes with the burden that the webserver shouldn't serve the file out if one requests it in a URL. Or are there prefab names to choose from?

Can anyone answer this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In previous versions of ASP.NET root of the project was also a root for the website. Some mechanisms were created to prevent access to files which should not be accessible to the outside world (like a whitelist of mime types, RequestFilteringModule).

This changed in ASP.NET 5 as a website root is no longer a project root.
Website root folder is a subfolder in your project directory (named *wwwroot* by default, but can be changed in project.json).
This means that **everything outside a website root folder is not accessible** to the outside world.

*config.json* file is outside of wwwroot so it won't be ever handled by any requests.