# How to load configuration file into auto-generated settings class object

Tags: c#, asp.net, configurationmanager

I need to break application settings in two files, one for external resources access, like a share folder or a web service url, and other for all the rest.

To keep configuration access simple in code i added a new Settings file, called `ExternalResourceSettings`. These settings files are derive from `ApplicationSettingsBase`.

How can i load an object of this class from a specific configuration file?

For clarification, the ExternalResourceSettings looks like these:

```
internal sealed partial class ExternalResourceSettings: global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {
...
}
```

ConfigurationManager class can load any config file to a Config object in 3 lines:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();                    
configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "Some path";

// Get the mapped configuration file
var config =ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

But how to convert it to ExternalResourceSettings? Or can ExternalResourceSettings  be loaded from a specific file in a other way?

Note: ExternalResourceSettings default constructor reads from default configuration file.

Comment: have a look at [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/78d8a9a4-9ff9-4154-8d60-c70b0f6a85ba/systemconfiguration-how-to-cast-appsettingssection-object-to-applicationsettingsbase-or?forum=netfxbcl) or [this](https://putridparrot.com/blog/user-application-settings-using-applicationsettingsbase/)

Comment: The solution presented is kind of brute force solution: Wrap all settings, one by one, in  another class. I am looking for some solution built-in the framework to avoid doing all that work.

Comment: [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/78d8a9a4-9ff9-4154-8d60-c70b0f6a85ba/systemconfiguration-how-to-cast-appsettingssection-object-to-applicationsettingsbase-or?) as well it says the same thing

Comment: if you could use appsettings.json for ExternalResourceSettings, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55019290/) could work..

Comment: Yes, but is not a strong typed solution and not even avoids to use strings for keys. A wrapper class gives works but is better than just use appSettings. It is odd how there is no native solution. I am looking for packages now, packages  that may extend configuration in this way.