# how to override value in appsettings.json file between 2 different projects using .NETCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, appsettings

I have a C# class library project and I am using *appsettings.json* to read values.
I have one MS Test (unit test) project and I am maintaining another *appsettings.json* file

appsettings.json file in C# Class library project:

```json
{
  "name" : "jack"
}
```

appsettings.json file in MS Test project:

```json
{
  "name" : "Mike"
}
```

My requirement is when I run the unit test the value **"name"** in the *appsettings.json* file in the C# class library project needs to be replaced with *appsettings.json* file in the MS Test project.

Comment: Check the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38398022/access-from-class-library-to-appsetting-json-in-asp-net-core
If it is helpful for you.